# NSUserDefaults objectForKey output comparison doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

I've got this code to read a preference. The output to the console is 1, but the window is not set to NSModalPanelWindowLevel. I have tried to use 1 instead of @"1" but that doesn't work either.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

NSString *alwaysonforeground = [defaults objectForKey:@"alwaysonforeground"];
 if (alwaysonforeground == @"1")
  [window setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
 NSLog(alwaysonforeground);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this function

```
if ([alwaysonforeground isEqualToString:@"1"]) { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm very new to Mac programming so I didn't know I had to do this.

Comment: No problem. I also had to find it out by myself because I didn't know it either. If you want to you can accept this answer.